Understanding the Cartesian Product of a Set with the Empty Set
Suppose I have a set $A$ defined as $A = \{\emptyset\}$.
When I calculate $A \times A$, the Cartesian product of $A$ with itself, should the result be $\emptyset$ or $\{(\emptyset, \emptyset)\}$?
Further more if the correct answer is $\{(\emptyset, \emptyset)\}$ would $(\emptyset,\emptyset)$ = $\{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset\}\}$
Because I've read a related question on proving that $\emptyset$ is a set of ordered pairs, but I'm struggling to prove/understand how it applies here.

My (Probably faulty proof)
Prove $\emptyset \text{ is a set of ordered pairs. }$
$\emptyset$ by definition is a set with no elements. Using the axiom of pairing, I can define a set $A$ such that $A = \{\emptyset\}$. This set $A$ can be constructed as $A = \{x : x \in \emptyset \text{ or } x \in \emptyset\}$.
By definition, a relation $R$ on a set $A$ is a subset of $A \times A$.
Given $A = \{\emptyset\}$, the Cartesian product $A \times A$ is:
$ A \times A = \{(\emptyset, \emptyset)\} $
The only subsets of $A \times A$ are $\{(\emptyset, \emptyset)\}$ itself or the empty set $\emptyset$. Thus, $R$ can either be $\{(\emptyset, \emptyset)\}$ or $\emptyset$.
Consider $R = \{(\emptyset, \emptyset)\}$. This means $(\emptyset, \emptyset) \in R$.
Now, by the definition of an ordered pair, $(\emptyset, \emptyset)$ is:
$ (\emptyset, \emptyset) = \{\{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \emptyset\}\} = \{\{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset\}\} = \{\{\emptyset\}\} $
Therefore, we have:
$ (\emptyset, \emptyset) \in R \subseteq A \times A $
Since $x = \emptyset$ and $y = \emptyset$, and $(x, y) \in R \subseteq A \times A$, it follows that:
$ (x, y) = (\emptyset, \emptyset) $
Thus, finally:
$ (x, y) \in R \subseteq A \times A $
is true.
Now suppose, for contradiction, that $\{(\emptyset, \emptyset)\}$ is not a set of ordered pairs. This would imply that there exists an element in $A \times A$ that is not an ordered pair, which contradicts the definition of $A \times A$ as the Cartesian product of $A$ with itself, where $A = \{\emptyset\}$.
Given the construction of $A \times A = \{(\emptyset, \emptyset)\}$, and the fact that the only element in this set is $(\emptyset, \emptyset)$, which is indeed an ordered pair, the assumption leads to a contradiction.
Therefore, $\emptyset$ can be considered a set of ordered pairs.

"define a set $A$ such that $A = {\emptyset}$. This set $A$ can be constructed as $A = {x : x \in \emptyset \text{ or } x \in \emptyset}$."  That is not correct.

Your $R$ is irrelevant. And your suppose, for contradiction, that ${(\emptyset, \emptyset)}$ is not a set of ordered pairs [...] *the assumption leads to a contradiction.
Therefore, $\emptyset$ can be considered a set of ordered pairs* is wrong.

In order to prove that $\varnothing$ is a set of ordered pairs by considering $A\times A$ for some set $A$, don't define $A$ as the set ${\varnothing}$. Instead, take $$A:=\varnothing.$$ This way, $A\times A$ will be equal to $\varnothing$.

Incidentally, you were correct that your (however useless) set $A:={\varnothing}$ can be defined using the axiom of pairing, but you did not write it correctly. It should be $$A = {x : x = \emptyset \text{ or } x = \emptyset}$$ instead of your $A = {x : x \in \emptyset \text{ or } x \in \emptyset}$.

Question doesn't match the title. "Cartesian product of a set with the empty set" means $X \times \emptyset$, not ${\emptyset} \times {\emptyset}$.

Thank you all it means a lot i realize my mistake

also ye i just realise my mistake i think i was thinking bout axiom of unions not pairing and ruined my proves also i meant the title to be  "Cartesian product of a set with the set containing an {empty set}"

Remember that
$$
X \times Y := \{ (x,y) \mid x \in X, y \in Y \}
$$
There is no concern if the $x$'s or $y$'s is the empty set, so
$$
A \times A = \Big\{ (\varnothing,\varnothing) \Big\}
$$

The typical formal definition of the ordered pair $(x,y)$ due to Halmos is
$$
(x,y) := \Big\{ \{x\}, \{x,y\} \Big\}
$$
Hence
$$
(\varnothing,\varnothing) = \Big\{ \{\varnothing\}, \{\varnothing,\varnothing\} \Big\} = \Big\{ \{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing\} \Big\} = \Big\{ \{\varnothing\} \Big\}
$$
Note that this means that $A \times A$ would be the thrice-nested emptyset:
$$
A \times A = \Big\{ \big\{ \{\varnothing\} \big\} \Big\}
$$


This set $A$ can be constructed as $A = \{x : x \in \emptyset \text{ or } x \in \emptyset\}$.

This is untrue, no matter how I twist it.

This redundancy of "$x \in \varnothing$ or $x \in \varnothing$" would make $A = \varnothing$
If you meant "$x \in \varnothing$ or $x \not \in \varnothing$", many things satisfy the latter half that aren't in your desired definition of $A$.

To be honest, I'm not sure what a formal approach to $A$ would achieve anyways. You presumably know the empty set exists; $A$ is just the set containing it.


Therefore, $\emptyset$ can be considered a set of ordered pairs.

It is not clear to me that you did anything other than prove that $A \times A$ is a set of ordered pairs.

Frankly, I think the proof of "$\varnothing$ is a set of empty pairs" becomes trivial since every element of it (precisely zero of them) are an ordered pair. Just like how every element in the empty set is even, and every element in it is odd. The underlying principle is just vacuous logic.

Ah, I was completely misled by the title. Thanks, @ArturoMagidin.

I think that encoding of ordered pairs is due to Kuratowski.

Ah thank you i realize my mistake
